# An action(ADD_CONTACT) is not getting executed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

ADD_CONTACT action is not getting executed. I want to display the contact details which is done by the ContactDetailComponent.js when i click on a particular contact which is present ContactListComponent.js . Can you please tell me where i am making mistake.(Contact details are not getting displayed when i click the button in ContactListComponent.js)

this is the component where all the contacts are displayed(ContactListComponent.js)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavItem, Card, CardBody, Nav, Button } from 'reactstrap';
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addDetails } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
//import { Details } from '../redux/detail';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addDetails: (contact) => dispatch(addDetails(contact))
});

// const mapStateToProps = state => {
//     return {
//         details: state.details.contact
//     }
// }

function ContactList(props) {
    if (props.isLoading) {
        return (<span className="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw"></span>);
    }
    else if (props.errMess) {
        return (<div className="bg-danger"><p>{props.errMess}</p></div>);
    }
    else {
        if (props.Contacts) {
            const contactl = props.Contacts.map((contact) => {
                return (
                    <NavItem key={contact._id} >
                        <Card >
                            <CardBody >
                                <Button onClick={() => addDetails(contact)}>{contact.username}</Button>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </NavItem>)

            });
            return (
                <Nav vertical>
                    {contactl}
                </Nav>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div><p>No contacts present</p></div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactList);
```

this is the component where the contact details are displayed(ContactDetailComponent.js).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { } from 'reactstrap';
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        details: state.details.contact
    }
}
function ContactDetails(props) {
    console.log(props.details);
    if (props.details) {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h3>username: </h3>
                <p>{props.details.username}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContactDetails);
```

[this is my github repository for my project](https://github.com/chakradhar7/address-book)

[this is permalink for the line where the button to show the details is present](https://github.com/chakradhar7/address-book/blob/f4b510a3792beea85f281a6aed51f6c2e44b9802/address-book-frontend/src/components/ContactListComponent.js#L32)

Comment: It should be `props.addDetails ` in the `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

You're using "addDetails" action
but you have to use the "addDetails" props which has the "dispatch" mechanism.
Just change **addDetails** for **props.addDetails**